# What Provider to use?

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am struggling to connect to an SQL database from a VB.NET application using OLEDB.  I usually connect to databases using ADO.NET or ODBC for Oracle.  The connection string I am using is as follows:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;Initial Catalog=database;Data Source=server;
```

The error I get is: "Additional information: Cannot open database 'database' requested by the login. The login failed."

The database, username and password are definitely correct.  I have confirmed this by logging onto SQL Studio Manager and connecting to the database successfully.

Therefore it has to be the Provider that is incorrect.  I have tried a few different providers e.g. SQLOLEDB.1.  How do I find out exactly what provider to use?

Comment: Did you try this: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/standard-security/

Comment: By "SQL database" do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: @plutonix, yes thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the server and the connection string issue is resolved. I would delete the question, but there are answers from other users.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with OLEDB.  Since you're using SQL Server, just use the built-in .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server ([list of .NET data providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx)).

In fact, you don't even need to worry about getting the connection string syntax just right.  You can use a built-in connection string builder for that too.

Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

// ...

Dim connStringBuilder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
connStringBuilder.DataSource = "myservername"
connStringBuilder.UserID = "myusername"
connStringBuilder.Password = "mypassword"
connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "mydatabase"

Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStringBuilder.ToString())
    conn.Open()

    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT mycol FROM MyTable", conn)
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Do While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine("Managed to fetch: {0}", reader("mycol"))
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I would normally do.  I am analysing some code that someone else has written that does not work because of the connection string.  Your answer did not help me, but it is a valid answer so +1.

Comment: For what it's worth, I manage to connect to a SQL Server 2014 database using an OleDbConnection using your connection string.  Can you try connecting to the same database using a more standard approach (using SqlConnection) to see if you get the same error?